# NOP instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I have recently learned that `nop` instruction is actually `xchg eax, eax`... what it does is basically exchanges `eax` with itself.

As far as CPU goes, does the exchange actually happen?

Comment: [At one time it did, and it was no longer a NOP](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=6).

Comment: @DCoder What do you mean?

Comment: Read the page I linked to. There was a bug in some AMD's x64 processors where `xchg EAX, EAX` was actually executed... [Most 32 bit instructions in x64 mode zero out the upper 332 bits of their operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register) , and this instruction did too.

Comment: @DCoder What about 32bit. Is it still relevant?

Comment: it doesn't have any effect on 32-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several instructions, which could be used depending on the compiler. `xchg eax, eax` is byte code 90. It is a legit instruction, which takes up a single processing cycle. In addition, there are several other instructions, which could be used in place of `xchg eax, eax`:

```
lea eax, [eax + 0x00]    byte code 8D 40 00
mov eax, eax             byte code 89 C0
```

Since all of those instructions are different length, compiler chooses one of the most appropriate versions depending on alignment requirements.

Regarding compilers' choices, a few pointers:

- GAS (GNU Assembler, used by GCC) x86 NOP operations can be found in function [i386_align_code()](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/master/gas/config/tc-i386.c)
- similarly, for LLVM it is in [X86AsmBackend::writeNopData()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/X86AsmBackend_8cpp_source.html)

Comment: but they are probably less "NOP-like" than the xchg is.  Besides which, the documented multi-byte NOP is the "0f 1f /0" set.

Comment: The only other `nop` instruction is `0F 1F /0` which is `NOP r/m16` and `NOP r/m32` on supported CPUs. It may take anywhere from 3 to 9 bytes in x86-64, as per [Intel doc](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) (page 4-163). So even though you can use `mov eax, eax` and others an an alternative, it has a downside vs. real `nop` in that it blocks CPU pipeline and lacks other hardware optimizations that are implemented in the `nop` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "Yes."  In fact, if you experiment by generating machine language op codes directly you will discover that there is a whole range of operations that are effectively NOPs, all of which take a single processor cycle to execute.

While they are not technically "Documented," you will find that very close to the 0x90,

- `XCHG EAX, EAX`
- `XCHG EBX, EBX`
- `XCHG ECX, ECX`
- `XCHG EDX, EDX`

Comment: I don't think this is is true. I think the non-EAX take more cycles (3 and not 1) and I think all the XCHG versions actually 0 the higher order 32 bits on a x86_64. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053039/124486